# Push Notification is not received when the app is in background mode or it is force stopped iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented firebase push in iOS 10 using Swift 3.

When I send push from firebase, I can receive the push message but only when the app is in foreground mode. I don't receive any message when the app is in background mode or it is force stopped.

Code is given below:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?


  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      let authOptions : UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: authOptions,
        completionHandler: {_,_ in })

      // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
      // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
      FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

    } else {
      let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
        UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
      application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
                                           name: .firInstanceIDTokenRefresh,
                                           object: nil)
    FIRApp.configure()
    return true
  }

  func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
  }

  func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
    print("Disconnected from FCM.")
  }

  func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
  }

  func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    connectToFcm()
  }

  func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                   fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification

    // Print message ID.
    print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

    // Print full message.
    print("%@", userInfo)
  }

  // [START refresh_token]
  func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
      print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
    }
    // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
    connectToFcm()
  }
  // [END refresh_token]

  func connectToFcm() {
    FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
      if (error != nil) {
        print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
      } else {
        print("Connected to FCM.")
      }
    }
  }

}


@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

  // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                              withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

    // Print full message.
    print("%@", userInfo)
  }

  @available(iOS 10, *)
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("Userinfo \(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)")
    //    print("Userinfo \(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)")
  }
}

extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {
  // Receive data message on iOS 10 devices.
  func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("%@", remoteMessage.appData)
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample payload strcuture of what you're sending?

Comment: @AL. i am sending from firebase console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks guys for all your support. Here is the final working code for **iOS 10** using **Swift 3**.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?


  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      let authOptions : UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: authOptions,
        completionHandler: {_,_ in })

      // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
      // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
      FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

    } else {
      let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
        UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
      application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
                                           name: .firInstanceIDTokenRefresh,
                                           object: nil)
    FIRApp.configure()
    return true
  }

  func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
  }

  func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
    print("Disconnected from FCM.")
  }

  func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
  }

  func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    connectToFcm()
  }

  func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let chars = (deviceToken as NSData).bytes.bindMemory(to: CChar.self, capacity: deviceToken.count)
    var token = ""

    for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
      token += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [chars[i]])
    }

    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.unknown)

    print("Device Token = ", token)
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("Did Fail to Register for Remote Notifications")
    print("\(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                   fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification

    // Print message ID.
    print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

    // Print full message.
    print("%@", userInfo)
  }

  // [START refresh_token]
  func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
      print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
    }
    // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
    connectToFcm()
  }
  // [END refresh_token]

  func connectToFcm() {
    FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
      if (error != nil) {
        print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
      } else {
        print("Connected to FCM.")
      }
    }
  }

}


@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

  // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                              withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

    // Print full message.
    print("%@", userInfo)
  }

  @available(iOS 10, *)
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("Userinfo \(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)")
    //    print("Userinfo \(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)")
  }
}

extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {
  // Receive data message on iOS 10 devices.
  func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("%@", remoteMessage.appData)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As per your question you have successfully get the push notification in foreground but not in background mode. For that did you tick the `Remote Notification` in Background Modes section of Capabilities.

Please find the below screenshot for more information.

[image]

Hope it works for you.

Comment: what could be the broblem? i am using swift 3. is that the one causing this problem?

Comment: No it is not, I need to check it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `APNS` format.

default format look like this

```
{
    aps =     {
        "content-available" = 1;
    };
    "gcm.message_id" = value;
    title = value;
}
```

convert this one to this

```
{
    aps =     {
        alert =         {
            title = value;
        };

    };
    "gcm.message_id" = ;
}
```

Inside method didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken, add the following code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
  let tokenChars = UnsafePointer<CChar>(deviceToken.bytes)
  var tokenString = ""

  for i in 0..<deviceToken.length {
    tokenString += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [tokenChars[i]])
  }

  FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Unknown)

  print("tokenString: \(tokenString)")
}
```

Comment: this is what i get ->  [AnyHashable("notification"): {
    body = "hey there..";
    e = 1;
    sound = default;
    sound2 = default;
    title = "Push Test";
}, AnyHashable("from"): 832003857052, AnyHashable("collapse_key"): com.crystaldelta.PushNotification]

Comment: now what is the APNS format you got after adding my code?

Comment: the same format as i have mentioned above. i am sending push from firebase console

Comment: @GaneshKumar ,  setting the priority of the message from normal to high should make it appear immediately. This is due to the way iOS bundles notifications and handles them. You can read about the https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127240/discussion-between-ganesh-kumar-and-sumit-garg).